# Preventing Text Overflow in Cells when Exporting Pandas DataFrame to Excel

Tags: python, pandas, excel, xlsxwriter, openxlsx

I'm working with Pandas to export a DataFrame to an Excel file using the DataFrame.to_excel() method. However, I'm encountering an issue where longer text entries spill over into adjacent cells in the generated Excel file. I'm looking for a way to ensure that the text in each cell is contained within its boundaries, either through wrapping or adjusting the cell size.
Here's an example:

```
import pandas as pd

# Sample DataFrame with long text entries
data = {'Column1': ['This is a very long text that might spill over', 'Short Text'],
        'Column2': ['Another long text that could overflow', 'More Text']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Exporting to Excel
file_name = 'sample_excel.xlsx'
df.to_excel(file_name, index=False)
```

Any solutions to ensure the text stays within its cell boundaries would be greatly appreciated!